# Push importHTML formula in a GSheets cell with Goosle Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm absolutely not a dev or anything but I'm searching everywhere to make this work.

I run a swim club and I'd like the members to have a cool app to check everything about the organization. Events, calendar, best times,.. I'm currently building it with Glide and therefore I'm using GSheets as a database.

Trying to automate things a little bit, I've already managed that for every swimmer registering on the app, it creates a new line in my master worksheet with the name of the swimmer and the link to his profile on a swimming data bank website. When my script is executed, a new worksheet is created and the row with the name and the link are also appended to the right worksheet.

Well, I have two problems now.

1. I'd like to push an importhtml formula in a 3rd column
2. I'd also like that the row with the name and link in every worksheet doesn't duplicate each time the script is executed.

```
function createNewSheets() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Liste de nageurs');
  
  // Get range with data from original sheet:
  var firstRow = 1;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var numRows = masterSheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = masterSheet.getLastColumn();
  var data_range = masterSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();

  // Iterate through all rows of data from Sheet1:
  for (var i = 1; i < data_range.length; i++) {
    var col = data_range[i]; // Current row
    var swimmerName = col[0]; // swimmer name
    // Get sheet with current swimmer name:
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(swimmerName);
    // Check if sheet with current swimmer name exists. If it doesn't it creates it:
    if (!sheet) {
      sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(swimmerName);
    }
    // Appends current row of data to the new sheet:
    sheet.appendRow(col)
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me on that one ?
It would save me a huge time to focus on other important features

Comment: Are you trying to add a link to the third column, or import data from a website into the 3rd column? Also, your variable names are a little confusing, you are using the variable 'col' for the values of a row, why not 'row'? Took me awhile to follow what was going on

Comment: The configuration of my mastersheet is as followed :

row1       col1 : Name of the swimmer           col2 : Link  
row2       Bastien Soret                                  myURL

I'd like this to happen when my script is executed :

Create a new tab with the name of the swimmer with this configuration in row 1 :

A1:Bastien Soret             A2:myURL         A3:=IMPORTHTML(A2; "table"; 4)


Is it better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code Change:

*You need to insert the formula using the `setFormula()` method.*

```
// Split your data range into values and formulae:
var data_range = masterSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols)
var data_values = data_range.getValues();
var data_formulae = data_range.getFormulas()

for (var i = 1; i < data_values.length; i++) {
    var col = data_values[i]; // Current row
    var swimmerName = col[0]; // swimmer name

    // Get sheet with current swimmer name:
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(swimmerName);

    // Check if sheet with current swimmer name exists. If it doesn't it creates it:
    if (!sheet) {
      sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(swimmerName);
    }

    // Set the first row rather than append the data:
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, col.length).setValues([col])
    sheet.getRange(1, 3).setFormula(data_formulae[i][2])
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

I get what you are trying to do.
Problem is, you can't do getFormulas as there's no formula in the row created in my master sheet. It needs to be added automatically in the new sheet with the swimmer name. And I can't add it in my master sheet beforehand because it's a IMPORTHTML formula importing a large table.

Is it clear enough for you ?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. What is the form of the formula you want? Do you have an example?

Comment: So, in my master sheet, coming from another file, I get a new row with swimmer name and his personal link everytime someone new subscribes to the app:  
  
A1 : Name,  
A2 : Link,  
  ///  
When executing the script, a new tab should be created with the name of the swimmer and a new row in this tab, with three columns as followed :  
  
A1 : Name,  
A2 : Link,  
A3 : =IMPORTHTML(A2; "table"; 4)

Comment: @BastienSoret Can you not simply use `=sheet.getRange(1, 3).setFormula("=IMPORTHTML(A2; "table"; 4)")` then?

Comment: It says Synthax Error missing a ")"

Comment: Thanks ! I found a workaround that makes my code work. Thanks to you and another thread to format the set formula correctly.

Comment: `sheet.getRange(1, 3).setFormula(‘=IMPORTHTML(A2; “table”; 4)’)` - use single quotes